# Save attached PDF Files from gmail with name of subject as title

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

To download several PDF files from gmail I'm using the following script. It works fine, there is just a detail I need to change. I need the name of the downloaded PDF-File to be name of the subject title of the mail. If tried to modify it, but it doesn't work :/ Any hints which line I have to change to get the desired output?

```
function GmailToDrive(){
  //build query to search emails
  var query = '';
  //filename:jpg OR filename:tif OR filename:gif OR fileName:png OR filename:bmp OR filename:svg'; //'after:'+getDateNDaysBack_(1)+
  for(var i in fileTypesToExtract){
    query += (query === '' ?('filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  query = 'label:inbox-Gesellschafter is:unread ' + query;
//  query += ' after:'+getDateNDaysBack_(1);
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
  var parentFolder;
  if(threads.length > 0){
    parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
  }
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j in mesgs){
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
//      var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
//      if(!isDefinedType) continue;
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(label);
  }
}

//This function will get the parent folder in Google drive
function getFolder_(folderName){
  var folder;
  var fi = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  if(fi.hasNext()){
    folder = fi.next();
  }
  else{
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
  }
  return folder;
}

//getDate n days back
// n must be integer
function getDateNDaysBack_(n){
  n = parseInt(n);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - n);
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
}

function getGmailLabel_(name){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  if(!label){
    label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);
  }
  return label;
}

//this function will check for filextension type.
// and return boolean
function checkIfDefinedType_(attachment){
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if(fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) !== -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just modify the existing code by getting the subject and then using it in your existing code.

```
var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();

// now also get the subject
var subject = mesgs[j].getSubject()

// now use the subject
 var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob).setName(subject)
```

Comment: Wow cool, you did it :) Thank you so much, you made my day :)